# Как выделить область изображения по цвету?

Tags: c++, массивы, qt, изображения, машинное-зрение

В ходе работы встала задача выделить соседствующие пиксели по цвету, однако я никак не додумаюсь, как это сделать. Если как в одной строке вполне понятно, то алгоритм действий по вертикали для меня пока загадка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какой-нибудь проект с открытым исходным кодом не слишком большого размера, чтобы его можно было подсмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, разобрался сам. Это можно сделать применив рекурсивную функцию, осуществляющую осмотр соседних клеток, игнорируя обработанные.

```
void Worker::fill(QPoint point) {
    QColor pointColor = QColor(image.pixel(point));
    if (ignore.contains(point)) {
        return;
    } else if (compare(templColor, pointColor)) {
        ignore.insert(point);
        image.setPixelColor(point.x(), point.y(), fillColor);
        QList<QPoint> bounding = border(point);
        QList<QPoint>::iterator iter;
        for (iter = bounding.begin(); iter != bounding.end(); iter++) {
            fill(*iter);
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Уже осмотренные клетки заносятся в `ignore`. Это контейнер вида *множество*, именно его применение позволяет избежать зацикливания на повторах. Полные исходный код выложил в свободный доступ в [этом](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qt-magic-wand-tool) репозитории.